# adding new records to a map under a same name

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a small program with Data.Map that stores employee IDs and names and you can insert, delete, lookup, etc..

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
main = do
  let emptymap = M.empty
      map1 = M.insert 10001 "John" emptymap
  print (M.lookup 10001 map1)
```

From here, if I added another employee to the map1, do I need to give it a new name ? If I added the following line, it does not compile.

```
      map1 = M.insert 10002 "Paul" map1
```

But if I added the following line, it works (it gives a lot of warnings though)

```
      map2 = M.insert 10002 "Paul" map1
```

I can create a new map with two employees with fromList() but every time I add a new employee (or delete an employee), I have to give a new name to the result?  I want to have a map that has the latest information under the same name. Please help.

Comment: What warnings do you get?

Comment: You seem to want mutability in a language which was designed to forbid it. For those cases where you do need it, you achieve either with a recursive function (which calls itself with the "new" updated value), or through e.g. a state monad. But I'm not yet convinced that you really need that -- what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily; you can chain the inserts together via composition:

```
main = do
  let emptymap = M.empty
      map = M.insert 10001 "John" . M.insert 10002 Paul $ emptymap
  print (M.lookup 10001 map)
```

If you want to add another name *later*, you need a new name; otherwise, you define an "infinite" map.

```
main = do
  let emptymap = M.empty
      map = M.insert 10001 "John" . M.insert 10002 Paul $ emptymap
  print (M.lookup 10001 map)
  let map' = M.insert 10003 "Kate" map
  print (M.lookup 10003 map)
```

If you need access to the same map in multiple places, though, you likely want to work in a `State` monad that will take care of managing all the references to the map for you.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Haskell are immutable. If you want mutable state, you can use a mutable reference type such as `IORef` (or `STRef`):

```
import Data.IORef (modifyIORef', newIORef, readIORef)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type Employees = Map Id Name
type Id = Int
type Name = String

main :: IO ()
main = do
    employees <- newIORef (Map.empty :: Employees)
    addEmployee employees 10001 "John"
    addEmployee employees 10002 "Paul"
    print . Map.toList =<< readIORef employees

addEmployee :: IORef Employees -> Id -> Name -> IO ()
addEmployee employees id name
    = modifyIORef' employees (Map.insert id name)
```

However, this isn’t very testable or composable—you’re stuck with `IO` (or `ST`). You can use `State` to make it pure:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State (evalState, modify, gets)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ flip evalState (Map.empty :: Employees) $ do
    modify $ addEmployee 10001 "John"
    modify $ addEmployee 10002 "Paul"
    gets Map.toList

addEmployee :: Id -> Name -> Employees -> Employees
addEmployee = Map.insert
```

Then all your modification and query functions on the state (such as `addEmployee`) can be pure, and you can test them in isolation:

```
removeEmployee 10001 (addEmployee 10001 "John" Map.empty)  ==  Map.empty
findEmployee 10002 Map.empty  ==  Nothing
```

If you need to interleave some other effects such as I/O with this state, you can use `StateT`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- flip evalStateT (Map.empty :: Employees) $ do
        lift $ putStrLn "modifying"
        modify $ addEmployee 10001 "John"
        lift $ putStrLn "modifying again"
        modify $ addEmployee 10002 "Paul"
        lift $ putStrLn "returning"
        gets Map.toList
    print result
```